# Throwing exception or raising a domain event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, notifications, domain-driven-design, entity

Consider the following piece of code:

```
public class Article : AbstractEntity<Article> {    

    // ...

    public void AppendFeedback(Feedback feedback) {
        var quota = this.FeedbacksQuota ?? this.DefaultFeedbacksQuota;            
        if(this.Feedbacks.Count >= quota) {
            throw new ApplicationException("message");
        }
        this.Feedbacks.Add(feedback);
    }

    // ...
}
```

So I don't know how would I notify users when quota gets exceeded. Throwing an exception seems bad to me. Is it the right place to use `domain events`? (Examples are appreciated, especially in context of `ASP.NET MVC application`).

Where should I gather/handle the messaging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your feedback quota is an invariant (business rule) then an exception is fine.

You can always add a method such as:

```
public bool CanAddFeedback
{
    get { return this.Feedbacks.Count < quota; }
}
```

To check whether feedback is allowed before adding so that you can return a meaningful/user friendly message.

You *could* raise a domain event on feedback added that contains the quota left, etc.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your both advices!